# Implementing parallax on a simple template

Tags: html, css

This is my template: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/qXPvq/1/

I've got everything how I want it, except that the green background I want to be stationary and have the content scroll on top of it, just like the parallax effect.

HTML

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="jumbo">test<br />test</div>
     <div id="select">menu</div>
    <div id="features">1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />1
        <br />1
    </div>
</body>
```

I know this kind of effect can be achieved with CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fiddle wasn't working for me, but you should be able to just do:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

In your CSS for whatever element has the background. Hope it works!